# How can I call a new table from a different prompt?

Tags: sql, sas

Good morning experts.

I have some monthly tables. Some are called Alpha_YYYYMM and the other Beta_YYYY_MM. When calling these tables I use two variable prompts, A and B where the diference is only the "_". How can I call table Alpha and Beta using only one prompt in SAS SQL?
I currently call the tables as:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.ALPHA_CURRENT_MONTH AS 
   SELECT DISTINCT *
        FROM PMIFDMSL.ALPHA_&delta;
QUIT;
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.BETA_CURRENT_MONTH AS 
   SELECT DISTINCT *
        FROM PMIFDMSL.BETA_&del_ta;
QUIT;
```

I've already tried:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.ALPHA_CURRENT_MONTH AS 
   SELECT DISTINCT *
        FROM PMIFDMSL.ALPHA_&delta;
QUIT;
%let a=%qsubstr(&delta,1,4);
%let b=%qsubstr(&delta,5,2);
%let del_ta=&a_&b;
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.BETA_CURRENT_MONTH AS 
   SELECT DISTINCT *
        FROM AREATEMP.BETA_&del_ta;
QUIT;
```

and other combinations.

But I keep getting this error message:

```
43          FROM AREATEMP.BETA_&del_ta;
NOTE: PROC SQL set option NOEXEC and will continue to check the syntax of statements.
NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "DEL_TA".
43          AREATEMP.BETA_2019_06)
                                           ____
                                           22
                                              ____
                                              76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, ;, (, ',', ANSIMISS, AS, CROSS, EXCEPT, FULL, GROUP, HAVING, 
              INNER, INTERSECT, JOIN, LEFT, NATURAL, NOMISS, ORDER, OUTER, RIGHT, UNION, WHERE.  

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why are you adding macro quoting by using %QSUBSTR() instead of %SUBSTR() if the values are going to be part of a name?  Characters that can be part of a name do not require macro quoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro quoting is probably confusing the compiler into thinking that `BETA_&del_ta` expands into more than one word, even though there are no spaces.

Also you did not define any macro variable named `A_` that you are using in your third `%LET` statement.

Try this instead.

```
%let a=%substr(&delta,1,4);
%let b=%substr(&delta,5,2);
%let del_ta=&a._&b;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it cause of concatenating macro variable in `%let del_ta=&a_&b;`.

Try to use :

```
%let del_ta=%sysfunc(catx(_,%nrstr(%superq(a)),%nrstr(%superq(b))));
```

Comment: Almost worked. The variable gets set to YYYY_M if M is less than month 10. For example, it gets the of 2019_6, even though a is 2019 and b is 06.

Comment: @RicardoHenriques ok, anyway Tom's answer better:)

Comment: In general it is not a good idea to try to use `cat...()` functions with `%sysfunc()`. Because they can take both numeric and character arguments sysfunc has to try to figure out what types of values you are sending them and that can cause issues.